# Magento 1.9 "Unable to list current working directory."

Tags: php, magento-1.9, magento1

I am getting this error in Magento 1 - **"Unable to list current working directory."** while trying to forgot password in frontend after adding email and captcha. I have attach reference for error bellow.
[Frontend Forgot Password error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdBpd.png)

- Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, Coding is not for this area. We are getting this error after moving forward in Forgot password process. you can check the image i have added in the description. - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your locale is `en_US`, then make sure the email template exists at

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/password_or_email_changed.html
```

If you are using other locale, then make sure the folder and file exists at

```
app/locale/{locale}/template/email/password_or_email_changed.html
```